# Launch the app on Gear S2

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm using Tizen Studio to launch the tamplate app BasicUI on my Gear S2.

My error:

[image]

When I tried to install from sdb:

The problem is related to the certificates. I did generate my certificate in Certificate Manager with one generate author certificate and the automatic certificate for distributor.

What is to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method.

`Connection Explorer` - `right click target(show context menu)` - `Permit to install applications`

And Try install again.